# Dynamically creating a CSRF token CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So, I've enabled the CSRF component in the initialize function of my AppController. But I have a function that gets submitted to via AJAX and sends data from dynamically created inputs that are not inside a form:

```
$('a#delete').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), $('input.delete:checked').serialize());
})
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to create the CSRF token for dynamically created inputs that are not inside a form?

I've read the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html) regarding the Csrf component, but it doesn't say anything on how to create a Csrf token, or even if it's possible with dynamically created inputs that aren't contained in a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `_csrfToken` as a form parameter after reading the cookie value:

```
var csrf = $.cookie('crsf');
$.post($(this).attr('href'), $('input.delete:checked').serialize() + '&_csrfToken=' + csrf);
```

Comment: It should be noted that copying this solution exactly as stated requires the use of the jQuery cookie plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie. But the main point of this solution is that you can read the Csrf token from a cookie and transfer it that way.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I have to send the request form .net application how I will add csrf token in request